# SQL Error in Table Creation

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I want to create table `Books`, My syntax:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please post plain text (using the `{}` code markup tool), not screen shots.

Comment: The error would appear to be that you are using angle brackets instead of parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using angle brackets (`<>`) where you should be using parentheses (`()`).

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    isbn INT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR (20),
    price DOUBLE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`create table books(isbn int primary key, name varchar(20), price double);`

Comment: An explaination as to how this may fix the problem is required (and anyways, what is the difference with the original query?)

Comment: The code is functionally identical to the code in Barmar's answer.  .